# Removing a folder from a library

Tags: windows-7, file-management, libraries

I've accidentally added a folder to a Library ( not the one I intended to), how can I remove it ? Is there a Library management tool or something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove folders you accidentally added to the library:

1. Right-click the affected library
2. Choose "Properties"
3. Select the tab "Library"
4. Select the folder you want to remove
5. Click on "Remove"

[image]

Comment: The library tab is not available for me, for the folder. I'm using build 7100, maybe the build doesn't have that feature ?

Comment: Oops - I overlooked the word "Affected library". Thank you, I was able to remove

Answer (score 1):

See this very detailed article with screen-shots:

[How to Remove a Included Folder from a Library in Windows 7](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/586-library-remove-included-folder.html)