# Relocate a library folder

Tags: windows-7, libraries

Out of the (Win7) box, the Public Pictures library points to C:\Users\Public\Pictures. I would like to reset that so it resolves to a secondary harddrive.

Comment: Related (reverse): [Removing a folder from a library](http://superuser.com/questions/50069/removing-a-folder-from-a-library)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you talking about the Pictures folder when you open a new windows explorer window?

If so, open the windows explorer and:
[image]

---

- Right click on Pictures

[image]

---

- Select Properties

[image]

---

- Click on Include a folder..

[image]

---

- Add the folder you wish to be used

[image]

---

- Select that folder in the Library locations: box
- Click on Set save location

[image]

---

- You can also remove the other given folders if you wish

Comment: on windows8 adding USB external folder: This folder can't be included because it is on a removable device

Answer (score 3):

Open `C:\Users\Public\` in Windows Explorer, right click on the `Public Pictures` folder and select `Properties`.

Inside of the Properties window, select the `Location` tab. Here you can specify the location the folder should be stored in.

[image: The Location tab in the Properties window]

Comment: OP is asking about changing the target of the library, not the user folder.  (Of course, if you want to move the folder, this is right, and you could just move the folder and not change the library for the same effect.)

Comment: @Shinrai: This is my interpretation of the question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Open your Windows Explorer. Right click on the "Pictures" Library, and hit **Properties.** Once it opens, you will see a list of folders that can be used. Hit the **include a folder** button, then navigate to the folder you wish to use. I tested this myself, using the Video's folder

[image: Library]